# jquery in wordpress plugin with depdendency

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

```
This is my first page of the plugin    


          <?php
        /*
        Plugin Name: guard_search plugin
        Description: Search Plugon
        Author: mazhar
        */   

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php' )));

       wp_register_style('jquery.formstyler', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/css/jquery.formstyler.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery.formstyler');

        wp_register_style('jquery.formstyler', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/js/jquery.formstyler.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery.formstyler');

        wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('prefix_bootstrap');

        wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_models_click', 'models_click');
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_models_click', 'models_click');

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_reset_years', 'reset_years');
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_reset_years', 'reset_years');
```

This is my ajax.js  where the problems lies where `styler is undefined`(problem) which is the part of jquery's formstyller plugin mentioned in my first page.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('input, select').styler({
                selectSearch: true,
            });
 });
```

1) My first question is how will i use jquery in my first page.

2) My second question is if i may how can i transport jquery.formstyller plugin in my ajax.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to load jquery.formstyler first to use it in your ajax.js.
You can **add it as another dependancie** like jquery itself.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery.formstyler' ) );
```

Also you have a little **syntax issue** in:

```
wp_register_style('jquery.formstyler', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/js/jquery.formstyler.min.js');
```

It should be register **script**, not *style*. same with the line below `wp_enqueue_style('jquery.formstyler');`. 
add as `wp_enqueue_script('jquery.formstyler');` script instead as style!

Comment: i have two files formstyler.css and formstyler.js. i should have two enqueue with different name? or same name

Comment: you can add them with the same name. but not both as a style. see `wp_register_style` is wrong for your script

Comment: so the bottom line is formstyler.css and formstyler.js would be added as wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script but with the same name

Comment: and wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery.formstyler' ) ); will be added next in the hierachy?

Comment: it has started giving me jquery.formstyler.min.js?ver=4.9.8:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined error now

Comment: yes, when you load the formstyler first. it will need jquery as dependencie too: `wp_register_script('jquery.formstyler', plugin_dir_url( _FILE_ ) . 'guards_search/js/jquery.formstyler.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );`

Comment: but ajax.js reference should be third after formstyler.cs and js?

Comment: at least after formstyler.js. nice that it works now :)